# Fill field with values with PK of another table using SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a table, Sales, with a field called VendorName and I have added another field called VendorID that is the FK of the table Vendors. How do I fill up the field, VendorID in the Sales table, so that it enters the appropriate VendorID that corresponds to the VendorName using SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
update sales
    set vendorid = (select v.vendorid from vendors as v where v.vendorName = sales.vendorName);
```

Comment: This is similar to the solution I devised and I get the same error from MS Access "Operation must use an updateable query." when I try to run your query.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
UPDATE SALES
INNER JOIN VENDORS ON SALES.VendorName = VENDORS.VendorName
SET SALES.VendorID = VENDORS.VendorID
```

Answer (score 0):

Have result set (salesID, VendorsID)  in either CTE or Temptable and use it with join condition .

`;with temp  as (
    select salesID, VendorsID  from sales s 
    join vendors v 
    on s.vendorName =v.vendorName
    ) 
    update sales
     set vendorid =t.VendorsID
     form  sales s
     join  temp  t
      on s.salesID =t.salesID`